# C# Two classes and two tables link

Tags: c#, mysql, database, class

I'm doing a project and I'm stuck at the beginning already
So I got two tables for two classes like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_Artikli] (
[Id]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Naziv]    NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[Sifra]    VARCHAR (13)   NOT NULL,
[Vp]       FLOAT (53)     NOT NULL,
[MP]       FLOAT (53)     NOT NULL,
[Napomena] NVARCHAR (300) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_Stanje] (
[Id]       INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Trenutno] INT           NOT NULL,
[Naruceno] INT           NOT NULL,
[Datum]    DATE          NOT NULL,
[Firma]    NVARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_T_Stanje_T_Artikli] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[T_Artikli] ([Id])
);
```

The 'Artikl' class and its table 'T_Artikli' works like a charm,the problem is with the other one. This chunk of code should store values in a table:

```
private void btnSacuvaj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CStanje sta = new CStanje();
    sta.Trenutno = Int32.Parse(txtTrenutno.Text);
    sta.Naruceno = Int32.Parse(txtNaruceno.Text);
    sta.Firma = txtFirma.Text;
    sta.Datum = DateTime.Parse(dtDatum.Text);
    Artikl art = new Artikl();
    art.ID = Int32.Parse(cbArtikli.SelectedValue.ToString());
    sta.Artikl = art;
    Console.WriteLine(sta.Trenutno);
    Console.WriteLine(sta.Naruceno);
    Console.WriteLine(sta.Firma);
    Console.WriteLine(sta.Datum);
    Console.WriteLine(art.ID);
    sta.dodajStanje();
    indeksSelektovanog = dgStanje.Rows.Count;
}
```

It returns this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_T_Stanje_T_Artikli". The conflict occurred in database "C:\USERS\MORSUS\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2015\PROJECTS\SEMINARSKI\EVIDENCIJA\EVIDENCIJA\BIN\DEBUG\EVIDENCIJADB.MDF", table "dbo.T_Artikli", column 'Id'.

On this line:

```
public void dodajStanje()
{
    string insertSql = "INSERT INTO T_Stanje " +
        "(Trenutno, Naruceno, Datum, Firma) VALUES " +
        "(@Trenutno, @Naruceno, @Datum, @Firma)";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = insertSql;
        //command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Sifra", Sifra));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Trenutno", Trenutno));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Naruceno", Naruceno));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Datum", Datum));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Firma", Firma));
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery(); //error
    }
}
```

I assume I did something wrong in the sql. Can anyone point me out please?

Another question about sql, how come my sql tables are saved for some only some time, eg 3-4 program runs. The data gets wiped after some time don't know when exactly.. And Copy to Output Directory is set to Copy if Newer.

Be free to ask for any more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this constraint is wrong below; you have the primary key of the T_Stanji table as both the primary key and the foreign key to the T_Artikli table, which can't happen.  Note both uses of the same column Id.

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_T_Stanje_T_Artikli] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[T_Artikli] ([Id])
```

You need to add an ArtikliID to the T_Stanje table:

```
[ArtikliID] INT (NULL | NOT NULL)
```

And then change this constraint to be:

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_T_Stanje_T_Artikli] FOREIGN KEY ([ArtikliID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[T_Artikli] ([Id])
```

So that the foreign key of this new column is mapped.

Comment: So the problem is in the same attribute name?

Comment: Just to be pedantic, having the PK also be an FK is valid in 1:1 relationships; it is that both are IDENTITY that is the issue. Only the "parent" should use IDENTITY.

Comment: Yes true @Uueerdo, good point. I was thinking based on the description it probably wasn't going to be the case, but yes possible.

Comment: @Morsus Yes generally you'd want to create a column just for the foreign key and use that in the link - that is the reason for the current error you are getting.  Is this a one to one or one to many relationship?